# Render multiple containers in react js

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I have to render multiple DOM elements from my JS.

Say I have `div`s like

```
  <div id="div1"><div>
   //Some Html tags
  <div id="div2"><div>
   //Some Html tags
  <div id="div3"><div>
   //Some Html tags
```

I need to render these three `div`s .
Each div will contain set of radio buttons. On click of any radio button in any div , I will execute a validation rest call , and based on the result I have to display only the valid radio buttons (that means I have to update each `div`s state.).

I used , something like this :

```
var divs=[
          {"name":"one","element":"div1"},
          {"name":"two","element":"div2"},
          {"name":"three","element":"div3"}
         ];
for(var elem in divs){
    ReactDOM.render(
            <ElementBox name = {divs[elem].name} / > ,
            document.getElementById(divs[elem].element)
    );
}
```

But event handling is hectic if I use this kind of approach . Means I couldn't find any way to update other `div`s state after validation.

Is there any other way to render multiple containers in a single element ?

Comment: `But event handling is hectic` - what do you mean?

Comment: Why do you need to use multiple `ReactDOM.render()` calls? In a typical React app you only have one.

Comment: My problem is , I have three div s, in different parts of the page .
Say <div id="div1"><div>
  // Some html tags

  <div id="div2"><div>

//some html tags 

  <div id="div3"><div>

I want to render these divs separately .

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is: typical react is to only have 1 `ReactDOM.render()` to start the react-engine. And do all additional rendering within react components.

Something like this:

```
class ElementsBox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div id={this.props.element}>{this.props.name}</div>
  }
}

class ElementsContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.elements.map(function(element) {
          return <ElementBox element={element} key={element.element}/>
        });}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ElementsContainer elements={divs}/>,
                document.getElementById('myreactrootinHTML'));
```

PS: unavoidable consequence of using react is that you always get a container within container, like this:

```
<div id='myreactrootinDOM'>    // needs to be here so react can launch somewhere
  <div>                        // react root can always only render 1 DOM element
    <div id='div1'></div>      // lower levels can have more than 1 component
    <div id='div2'></div>
    <div id='div3'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can even parse an array of elements and avoid the wrapper